# Selenium WebDriver returning ???? for language characters in UI when i use .getText()

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Okay i am trying to return header from modal. Title is मैं बढ़िया हूँ.
When i use 'get Text()' value on driver, it returns ?????
How do i make java return मैं बढ़िया हूँ and not ????? thanks

```
public String get Title(){
driver.FindElement(By.cssSelector(cssElement)).click();
waitForMonitorToBeVerified(cssElement);
String element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(cssElement)).getText();
util.print("UI: "+element);
         driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(cssElement)).click();
        return element;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Up to my knowledge This is not problem from selenium side. I think it is the problem from your eclipse (any other Java IDE) encoding problem.

see below post.

[How to use Special Chars in Java/Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200691/how-to-use-special-chars-in-java-eclipse)