# How to replace non-ASCII by ASCII in pandas data frame

Tags: python, unicode, pandas, ascii, dataframe

I have a pandas Data Frame from a Excel File as Input in my program.

I would like to replace some non ASCII characters in the pandas Data Frame.

```
import pandas as pd
XList=['Meßi','Ürik']
YList=['01.01.1970','01.01.1990']

df = pd.DataFrame({'X':XList,
                   'Y':YList})

      X           Y
0  Meßi  01.01.1970 
1  Ürik  01.01.1990
```

I would like to create some replace rules: eg. ß->ss and Ü->UE

and get this:

```
       X           Y
0  Messi  01.01.1970 
1  UErik  01.01.1990
```

Note: Im using Python 2.7

**UPDATE:**

Solved using the answer below and setting up by Eclipse following:

1°: Changing Text file encoding in Eclipe to UTF-8.

How to:
[How to use Special Chars in Java/Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200691/how-to-use-special-chars-in-java-eclipse)

2°: Adding to the first line command

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
```

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Python/article.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to create a dict and iterate over the k,v and use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.replace.html#pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.replace):

```
In [42]:

repl_dict = {'ß':'ss', 'Ü':'UE'}
for k,v in repl_dict.items():
    df.loc[df.X.str.contains(k), 'X'] = df.X.str.replace(pat=k,repl=v)
df

Out[42]:
       X           Y
0  Messi  01.01.1970
1  UErik  01.01.1990
```

**EDIT**

for editors that don't allow unicode encoding in the python script you can use the unicode values for the transliteration:

```
In [72]:

repl_dict = {'\u00DF':'ss', '\u00DC':'UE'}
for k,v in repl_dict.items():
    df.loc[df.X.str.contains(k), 'X'] = df.X.str.replace(pat=k,repl=v)
df

Out[72]:
       X           Y
0  Messi  01.01.1970
1  UErik  01.01.1990
```

Comment: I cant type non ASCII char in Eclipse in my code.
Do you know how could I rewrite this?
    repl_dict = {'ß':'ss', 'Ü':'UE'}

Comment: I suggest you use a different editor, I'm using IPython but you should be able to save unicode characters in your python script. Otherwise lookup how to enable unicode encoding in eclipse

Comment: Thank you! Problem solved with Eclipse. I updated it.