# Eclipse IDE - Inputted keys and File separator (Japanese to English)

Tags: java, eclipse, backslash, cjk

I'm trying to input backslash in my java file through Eclipse IDE.

When using File.separator, the return is **\**, so my program returns an error indicating that it cannot locate the file because of the path returned like this:

```
¥¥¥¥C:¥¥Users¥¥Test Folder\xls\Test.xls
```

Here's my pseudo-code:

```
String path = ¥¥¥¥C:¥¥Users¥¥Test Folder;
String pathToConcat = File.separator + "xls" + File.separator + "Test.xls";
```

I tried pressing the backslash in notepad and it returns **\**, but in eclipse, it is **¥**.

Comment: Have you tried copying and pasting it in from notepad in your string variable

Comment: The path returned? If it is copy paste from debugger to notepad I get ¥¥¥¥C:¥¥Users¥¥¥¥Test Folder\xls\Test.xls 
And if I copy paste \\\\C:\\Users\\Test Folder from notepad to java file in Eclipse. It returns ¥¥¥¥C:¥¥Users¥¥Test Folder

Comment: Can you see if this link to a similar problem helps you: https://superuser.com/questions/1167662/why-is-windows-10-displaying-as-%C2%A5-on-the-command-line/1167665

Comment: @KrishnanshuGupta The solution offered in the link above is applied to my pc currently. I ensured that my default language for non-unicode is English US

Comment: I'll try to look something up to hopefully help you.

Comment: Set the global text file encoding preference Workbench > Editors to "UTF-8". according to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200691/how-to-use-special-chars-in-java-eclipse

Comment: @KrishnanshuGupta Thanks! I now tried setting my language, region to Japanese and the program has no errors, it works, I have no issue in the path returned (¥¥¥¥C:¥¥Users¥¥Test Folder¥¥xls¥¥Test.xls). However changing it back to US, it is still the issue.

Comment: @gengencera, can you try typing alt 9 2, and then release alt key. This will only work on windows I believe. But the numbers have to be on the key/num pad thing

Comment: For an explanation, in windows you can press alt and then ascii code to get the specified character

Comment: That's as much as I can find on the internet, hope something I mentioned helps you.

Comment: The only other thing I can find is to change your region setting(which you said you've done) and to change your japanese fonts back to english(for all other ide's, word, etc; don't know about eclipse though)